# How to create a RDD for a single column in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new for spark scala Here I am trying to create a dataframe but I am facing a issue

```
  val date= "01-01-2012"
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(date)

    val df= rdd.toDF("date") // error value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.rdd
```

how to do that can any one please tell what is the reason for that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use toDF method you need to import `import sqlContext.implicits._`
or if you are using Spark Session

```
  val spark =SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
```

`parallelize()` method requires a `Seq`, `List` or `Array` which converts to a row from it.
So passing a single value does not make a sence
you can do following for a simple example

```
val date = Seq("01-01-2012", "01-01-2013", "01-01-2014")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(date).toDF("date")
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I have two table A and B with different columns. But I want to join two table which contains combination of A and B Columns How can I do

Comment: Here is a simple example of joining two dataframes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860511/join-files-in-spark/43861558#43861558 You can be more specific on what basis you are joining.

Answer (score 0):

1. For you to have access to toDF() method, you need to have import for sqlContext.implicits_, where sqlContext is an instance of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
2. Probably with a single value, toDF() method might not be able to associate with a default schema to create a DataFrame or Dataset. You might want to try this way

   `import sqlContext.implicits._
   val date= "01-01-2012"
   var rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(date))
   var df = rdd.toDF()
   df.show`

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have two table A and B with different columns. But I want to join two table which contains combination of A and B Columns How can I do